# Google Apps Script function does not return the true number of users accessing a file

Tags: google-apps-script

Let's say there is a file in a Team Drive folder and over 120 users have access to it. Most can edit the file, but some can only view it or comment on it. I wrote a script that logs the number of users who can only view this file, like so:

```
function t() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(/* folder ID */);
  var file = folder.getFiles().next();
  var viewers = file.getViewers();
  Logger.log(viewers.length);
}
```

That should log a number greater than 0, but it turns out it logs exactly 0. This can't be right because I checked the file myself, and indeed it has several users who have view-level access to the file.

Please help me understand what's going on and how I could go about fixing this problem!

Edit: On an unrelated note, why can't I get a commenter from a file the same way I can get an editor or a viewer? For instance, `file.getViewers()` and `file.getEditors()` are valid instructions, assuming that `file` is a [File object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file). But there is no `file.getCommenters()` instruction, even though there is a `file.removeCommenter()` instruction.

Comment: Instead of adding "unrelated notes" post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [getViewers()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getviewers):

> Gets the list of viewers and commenters for this
>   [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#).
>   If the user who executes the script does not have edit access to the
>   File, this method returns an empty array.

So you probably don't have edit access.

Comment: I just checked and I actually do have edit access to the files concerning this task

Answer (score 0):

getEditors() array does not include the file owner. See the [getOwner() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getowner).